# NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null, with @RNC/AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on a React Native project created with Expo. I've been using regular old `AsyncStorage`, importing from `react-native`, and all has been well.

In looking up how to mock `AsyncStorage` for testing, I saw that `react-native-community/react-native-async-storage` has its own mock built in.

So I installed the community plugin with `yarn add` and switched out all my import statements.

When I run my app, I'm getting an error (which I'm retyping myself, excuse some ellipses):

```
[@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.

To fix this issue try these steps:

-Run `react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage` in the project root.
-Rebuild and restart the app
-Run the packager with `--clearCache` flag.
-If you are using CocoaPods on iOS...
-If this happens while testing with Jest...
```

So I tried running `react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage` but I keep getting this error:

```
Something went wrong while linking. Error: Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null
```

Some research showed me that Expo apps can't (and don't need to) link.

I tried `npm start --clearCache` to no avail.

Also, I don't have an `ios` (or `android`) folder in my project. This has always been kind of confusing for me because I see it referenced all over the place. I run my app in the Simulator/Emulator (and device) through the Expo app. Once I tried ejecting and there were problems. So, I don't have an `ios` folder.

(I'll go back to using the old native `AsyncStorage` from `react-native` and creating a mock myself, but I'd like to know how to solve this, and similar problems that may arise in the future.)

Comment: I think it's better to erase the project, re-create it, and copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 38):

This error can be rectified by **linking** the module like mentioned above but **linking** does not work if your app is **Expo Managed** (created via expo-cli).

Assuming your app is Expo managed, 
instead of using the **AsyncStorage** from Facebook RN Documentation:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

Do:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
```

Check documentation here: [AsyncStorage Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/asyncstorage/)

Comment: this solution also doesn't work for me, it's not updating data in first time, please help I am working in a project whose deadline id 5 march means tomorrow.

Comment: Good, but deprecated answer, at the top of docs this note

Comment: If you're running on an Expo managed project, the above solution will no longer work in 2021. As documented on https://docs.expo.dev/guides/testing-with-jest/ you can now just add `yarn add jest-expo --dev`

Comment: This answer is deprecated! Install it via `expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage` (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/async-storage/), see the answer from @jonnyg23 below.

Answer (score 16):

What resolved this for me was to first install the following library:

```sh
expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

Then, update your import as such:

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
```

> Note: You may have to restart Expo after this fix.

Comment: This is the only valid answer around here!

Comment: This works for me too. It's a valid answer.

Comment: Thank you - after an entire afternoon of searching - this answer was the solution

Answer (score 5):

I just had a similar issue and found the answer provided by Krizzu on github very helpful. Here is what he says: 'If you're using expo, you cannot add this package. Use whatever expo gives you (and ignore the warning about deprecation).' and 'You cannot add additional native modules to expo, unless you eject your project.'

You can read more about this issue following the threads on:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage/issues/89 and https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage/issues/72.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just close the Metro bundler and run `react-native run-android or run-ios` and it will be fixed.

Comment: guy mentioned he is using expo. I think you need to eject first before running react-native run-ios

Comment: For non expo users - this is a correct solution to the problem. The better answer explanation would help

Comment: "BUNDLER" is the key! You have to rebuild your app UGH

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the reason was cuz I was using react-native-navigation and it messed up the android section in MainApplication.java, so I had to change the file manually, I had already run this command:

> react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage

now I have this:

```
   private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(new MainReactPackage(),
            new AsyncStoragePackage()); //<----- here
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
            return "index";
        }
    };
```

and this :

```
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        // Add additional packages you require here
        // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                // eg. new VectorIconsPackage()                    
                new AsyncStoragePackage()); //<----- here
    }
```

Comment: rephrase what you are describing, I didn't really understand. in my ```MainApplication.java``` looks like this:                                                            
        ```@Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }```

Comment: are you suggesting to remove this piece of code and replace with yours? or append them? both methods didn't work for me! note I am also using ```react-navigation``` and facing same issue here

Answer (score 2):

Let's try with [@react-native-async-storage/async-storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install)

And if still error I think you will follow the step in [this link](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/304#issuecomment-748644524)

- remove the app in the Ios simulator (this is the main step for fix the error)
- then `cd ios/ && pod install`
- if React Native <= 0.59 run `react-native link @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`.
- run `npm start --reset-cache`
- reinstall app with `react-native run-ios`

Hope that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while using react native AsyncStorage.
Try:

```
cd ios && pod install || npx pod-install
```

Note: For react native version higher than 0.60, linking is automatic.

Then just restart the app.

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

App should start up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

running

```
react-native link @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

after this running Metro with "`--reset-cache`" verbose and running "`react-native run-android`" in a fresh cmd resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by running the project again by

- **npx react-native run-android** command.

If you are using the **iOS Device** then:

- cd ios && pod install
- npx react-native run-ios

if still not works try installing the npm package again and follow the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage”/async-storage/src/AsyncStorage.native.js,
replace import RCTAsyncStorage from ‘./RCTAsyncStorage’ by import RCTAsyncStorage from ‘./RCTAsyncStorage.expo’;

Answer (score 0):

In package.json created link:

```
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage",
```

Answer (score 0):

Autolink `npx pod-install` didn't work for me.

I had to follow the [steps for manual linking](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/link) to eliminate the error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mostly happen when node_modules folder has been changed by installing new library or some sort of action. Please try removing cache and do yarn install or npm install again

```
$ npx react-native-clean-project
$ yarn install
```

Comment: Try to add this line in the file where you add the navigation:

import * as React from 'react';
this has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning cache and and restart the server, or you can rebuild the app

```
npm start --reset-cache
npm run android 
for ios: npm run ios
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by running the project again by

npx react-native run-android command.
If you are using the iOS Device then:

cd ios && pod install

npx react-native run-ios

if still not works try installing the npm package again and follow the official documentation.

Comment: npm start --reset-cache
npm run android 
for ios: npm run ios

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. install pods -> `pod install`
2. uninstall the app
3. install the app again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions above. My project is expo based react native project.

The only thing that worked was to remove the `ios` folder. And rebuild everything using `npx expo run:ios`.

If this doesnt work you could try again with `expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage` and then remove `ios` folder and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

For folks who are still facing this issue on the latest versions onf Expo (v48 and above)

Rebuild the application and generate the development build. This should resolve the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
npx expo-doctor

npx expo install --check
```

just run this two command for dependency conflicts and see magic, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The `@react-native-community/react-native-async-storage` is probably being used as a dependency for another library. But it's deprecated.

You should use `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` instead.